# Like on an user Model laravel 8

Tags: laravel

`enter code here`Hey guys i'm trying to add a like and a dislike on an user model on laravel 8, and it only works if the user liked is the authenticated user and could someone help me on how to make it possible with all user

User model :

this is the user model:

```
 class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'first_name',
        'image',
        'cover_image',
        'country_id',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];



    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UserLike::class,);
    }


}
```

this is the like model:
<?php

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\User;

class UserLike extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'liked_id',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

This is the like migrations:
<?php

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUserLike extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user_likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('liked_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('user_like');
    }
}
```

Controller :
class UserLikeController extends Controller
{
//
public function likeunlikeuser($id)
{

```
        $user = User::find($id);
        if(!$user)
        {
            return response([
                'message' => 'User not found.'
            ], 403);
        }

        $userlike = $user->likes()->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->first();

        // if not liked then like
        if(!$userlike)
        {
            UserLike::create([
                'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
                'liked_id' => $id,
            ]);

            return response([
                'message' => 'Liked'
            ], 200);
        }
        // else dislike it
        $userlike->delete();

        return response([
            'message' => 'Disliked'
        ], 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome at SO. I think you missed some code fences / code snippets blocks arround your code. Also there is a 'enter code here' section in the beginning

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

you don't need use Auth user inside your controller just let all users have the access to the function and also check your Route it should not have Auth middleware and your constructor function should not have middleware (Auth) too.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but sorry i've written the wrong question, my true problem is the like works on all user but when i delete it, it only works on the auth() user

Comment: $userlike = $user->likes()->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->first();

        // if not liked then like
        if(!$userlike)
        {
            UserLike::create([
                'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
                'liked_id' => $id,
            ]);

            return response([
                'message' => 'Liked'
            ], 200);
        }
        // else dislike it
        $userlike->delete();

        return response([
            'message' => 'Disliked'
        ], 200);

Comment: @HerizoRazafison Please revise your question to accurately describe the problem and include the code in your comment above.